# Ionic: ng-show and page transition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing a mobile app with Ionic but I'm not yet very familiar with this framework or Angular. There are some list items you can tap to see a page with some details.

This is my list template:

```
<ion-view view-title="In der Nähe">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-refresher
      pulling-text="Aktualisieren"
      on-refresh="loadData()">
    </ion-refresher>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item href="#/event/location-details" ng-click="showDetails(location)" ng-repeat="location in locations">
        {{location.name}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller:

```
  ...
  $scope.showDetails = function(location)
  {
    $rootScope.currentLocationDetails = location;
  };
  ...
```

And this is the details page:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{location.name}}">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <button ng-show="location.attr.wheelchair == 'yes'" class="button icon ion-paper-airplane button-balanced"></button>
    <button ng-show="location.attr.wheelchair == 'limited'" class="button icon ion-paper-airplane button-assertive"></button>
    <button ng-show="location.attr.wheelchair == 'no'" class="button icon ion-paper-airplane button-energized"></button>

    <button ng-show="location.attr.food == 'yes'" class="button icon ion-pizza button-balanced"></button>
    <button ng-show="location.attr.food == 'no'" class="button icon ion-pizza button-energized"></button>

    <button ng-show="location.attr.internet_access == 'yes'" class="button icon ion-wifi button-balanced"></button>
    <button ng-show="location.attr.internet_access == 'no'" class="button icon ion-wifi button-energized"></button>

    <button ng-show="location.attr.smoking == 'no'" class="button icon ion-no-smoking button-balanced"></button>
    <button ng-show="location.attr.smoking == 'yes'" class="button icon ion-no-smoking button-energized"></button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('DetailsController', function($scope, $rootScope)
{
  $scope.location = $rootScope.currentLocationDetails;
});
```

This works well on Android devices but there's a problem on iOS:

Angular seems to evaluate the ng-show directives after/during the page transition.

This is how it looks on Android:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aspI95Jm574

iPad running iOS 8:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCf3V8ewq40

You can see that all the buttons are visible during the animation.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug in Ionic? Is there a better way to pass the location object to the DetailsController in this case?

Please let me know if you need to see more of the code.

Thanks!

Comment: A known Ionic issue, see the discussion in the forum here http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/beta-14-ng-hide-show/14270/10

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround is to use **ng-hide** class on every element that has the **ng-hide** or **ng-show** attribute.

```
<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="isVisible">my element</div>
```

This will assure that the element is hidden before the angular compiles. Later on when angular boots up the ng-show/hide directive will take care of ng-hide class.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer both questions:

1. Set ng-cloak on the ion-content element in your details page. Additionally setup the following CSS:

   ```
   [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
       display: none !important;
   }
   ```

You can read up on ng-cloaks behaviour [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak).

2. I don't think it'll be much faster, but you can use a 'shareService' to share data between controllers, which might be considered 'cleaner':

   ```
   appServices.factory('shareService', function() {
       var shareService = {
           location : {}
       };
       return shareService;
   });
   ```

   In your overview controller inject the shareService and:

   ```
   $scope.showDetails = function(location){
       shareService.location = location;
   };
   ```

   In your DetailsController inject the shareService and:

   ```
   $scope.location = shareService.location;
   ```

   You could also make this one more elaborate, as an array with ids of the different locations.

Final thought would be to use one directive for all the different buttons, to make it more reusable. You could then skip rendering and then hiding the buttons that are not available in the selected location.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately the ng-cloak directive doesn't change anything. I tried applying it to the ion-content, a wrapper div and each of the buttons but none of these showed any effect. I also implemented the suggested shareService and it works well, thank you!

Comment: Did you use ng-cloak together with the suggested CSS? That's the important part. The ng-cloaked element will loose it's class as soon as it is rendered ready. Also, are there any highly specific CSS-selectors on your buttons, changing the disply attribute?

Comment: Yes, I've set up the CSS inline in my <head>. I also tried it with divs instead of buttons (like: <div style="width:20px;height:20px;background:red;" ng-hide="location.attr.wheelchair != 'yes'"></div>) but the result is the same. Also these divs are visible during the transition.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry this doesn't work. This is hardly going to be a satisfying answer, but let's try this: put an inline style="display: none !important" on every of your buttons, not the parent, but every element that has the ng-show attribute as well. Let's see if that helps. Btw, I read somewhere else, that having your angular.js included in the head instead of the body might also help.

Comment: When I set the suggested style attributes (w/ & w/o "!important") für every button, none of the buttons are visible anymore. But there's one more thing I observed: In Ionic the title collapses when it's too long to display. And also the back button caption changes just to 'Back'. On the details page the name of the location is displayed in the header bar (<ion-view view-title="{{location.name}}">). I tested it once again on my iPhone 4 (which is much slower and you can watch the effect a bit longer) and saw that the header title collapses at the same the buttons disappear...

Comment: ... So the location object is already there in the DetailsController before the transition starts. But it's evaluated (as well as the ng-show) after the animation start. To show you what I mean I uploaded another video: http://youtu.be/dSU2sH7a7DM (look at the header bar)

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this? My raw template code is always showing for a split second too on iOS page transitions, and ng-cloak isn't working.

Comment: I'm also suffering from this issue and have tried the various suggestions given here and elsewhere (all related to ng-clock and display: none !important;). Would love to hear about anyone who managed to work around this.